# "Failure creating file" exception when opening Excel file stored on SharePoint with C# and OleDB?

Tags: c#, excel, sharepoint, oledb

I am currently using interop with an Excel file stored on SharePoint without problems, but I need to use OleDB, and I get a "Failure creating file" exception on the `fill()` command. Here is my code:

```
        public DataTable ReadExcelFile()
    {
        sheetName = "Sheet1";
        path = "//abc.sharepoint.com/teams/RoboticProcessAutomation/coreteamarea/Shared%20Documents/Bot%20Tracker/Workspace%20Tracker.xlsx";

        using (OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection())
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            string fileExtension = Path.GetExtension(path);
            switch (fileExtension)
            {
                case ".xls":
                    conn.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + path + ";" + "Extended Properties='Excel 8.0;HDR=YES;'";
                    break;
                case ".xlsx":
                    conn.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + path + ";" + "Extended Properties='Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES;'";
                    break;
                default:
                    throw new Exception($"Invalid extension: {fileExtension}");
            }

            using (OleDbCommand comm = new OleDbCommand())
            {
                comm.CommandText = "Select * from [" + sheetName + "$]";
                comm.Connection = conn;
                using (OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter())
                {
                    da.SelectCommand = comm;
                    da.Fill(dt);
                    return dt;
                }

            }
        }
    }
```

I'm using .NET Framework 4.72

What am I missing?

Comment: You don't need to use the old Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0 driver. Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0 will open .xls and .xlsx just fine. The main problem however is that your file specification is URL encoded. OLEDB requires it to be a UNC path so replace those %20 with spaces. Finally, I've never been able to open SharePoint files directly with OLEDB. I've generally had to copy them somewhere else first. However, that may be because of security specific to my site and yours may work just fine. Also, pretty sure those forward slashes should be backwards ones.